# Heat and thermodynamical equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics

Does heat is sum of all All types of kinetic energies of all the molecules or just the translational k.E of molecules???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

It is neither. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. In other words, heat is energy in transit.

What you are describing is internal energy, specifically, internal molecular kinetic energy. It consists of molecular vibrational, rotational, and translational kinetic energy, as applicable to a specific substance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You see a system has an internal energy as you know the energy can be given by
$$U= \sum_i F_i x_i$$ where $U$ is internal energy $F_i $ and $x_i$ are generalized forces and displacement for example pressure and volume or chemical potential and number of particle.

If there are $n$ ways of doing work on a system the system will have $n+1$ generalized displacement the $+1$ comes from the heat,

Heat is the part of internal energy that is due to the Temperature (generalized force) and the entropy (generalized displacement)

The temperature is somewhat special as it is a consequence of zeroth law.